# How do I only read a certain part of this line into a structure?

Tags: c++, csv, structure

I am working with a csv file with a comma(,) as the delimiter. A certain line in the text file version of the csv file looks like this.

```
Station Name,MONTREAL/PIERRE ELLIOTT TRUDEAU INTL,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I want to be able to only store "MONTREAL/PIERRE ELLIOTT TRUDEAU INTL", minus the quotes. Therefore, i want to be able to not store STATION NAME. Based on my research, my code looks like this.

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct company_data
{
    string station_name, province, climate_identifier, TC_identifier, time_info;
    float latitude, longitude;
    int WMO_identifier;
    string E, M, NA, symbol;
};

void accept_company_data (company_data initial)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("eng-hourly-montreal-wind_dec_2015.csv");
    string line, temp1,temp2;
    getline (infile, line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    iss>>temp1;
    iss>>initial.station_name;
    cout<<initial.station_name;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is nothing more than parsing a CSV-formatted file. Go to Google, and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this

both of these use "C" string.  you can use string.c_str() to get that.

1. take a look at strtok() - this will break up a string based on some delimiter (in your case the comma).   on Linux/UNIX type 'man strtok'
2. set a pointer to the beginning of the string and loop till you hit the comma. Then increment the pointer by one (to pass over the comma) and save that position (set a pointer to it).  Now continue to look for the next comma.  When you have that next comma you can copy all the characters from the start pointer to the end pointer.

for example:

```
char *string = "you're input,with commas, in it";
char *start_pointer, *end_pointer, *ptr;

ptr = string;   
while (*ptr!=',') ptr++; // scan along looking for comma
ptr++;  // the above while, will have stopped on the comma
start_pointer=ptr;  
while (*ptr!=',' && *ptr) ptr++;
end_pointer=ptr;

//now you can copy to your destination
char destination_buffer[128];  
char *des=destination_buffer;
for(ptr=start_pointer;ptr<end_pointer;) *des++=*ptr++;
```

the above is not really efficient since you scan twice
what you could do is after you found the first comma
you can do

```
while(*ptr!=','&&*ptr) *des++=*ptr++;
```

the "&& *ptr " is looking for a NULL that delimits the end of a string.